# 3dCart API integration with rails2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, api, soap

I need to integrate my **rails 2** application with **3dCart API**. I want to make a request to get number of orders in the store.
to do this, I am following http://api.3dcart.com/cart.asmx?op=getOrderCount

I created the followin XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <getOrderCount xmlns="http://3dcart.com/">
      <storeUrl>https://echtest3d.3dcartstores.com/</storeUrl>
      <userKey>MY API KEY</userKey>
    </getOrderCount>
  </soap:Body>
```

then I am posting it as following

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("api.3dcart.com")
http.use_ssl = false
http.post("/cart.asmx", xml_file, {
               'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
               'Content-Length' => "#{xml_file.length}",
               'SOAPAction' => 'http://3dcart.com/getOrderCount' })
```

My problem is that, the response although it is

> Net::HTTP OK 200 OK readbody=true

it contains the following error node:

```
error trying to get data from the store. Technical description: The remote name could not be resolved: 'https'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Store URL shouldn't contain the `https` prefix, it should be just

```
echtest3d.3dcartstores.com/
```